# Can't select date of birth in django forms

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Well the problem is that i don't understand how to change selected years in form

for example i need to select years from 1995 but not from 2016

[image]

forms.py

```
class applyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='First name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ivanna'}))
    surname = forms.CharField(label='Last name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Diachuk'}))
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, label = 'Gender')
    dateOfBirth = forms.DateField(label='Date of birth', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    country = forms.CharField(label='Country of citizenship')
    city = forms.CharField(label='Current city')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    placeOfWorkOrStudy = forms.CharField(label='Place of work/study')
    speciality = forms.CharField(label='Speciality')
    motivationMessage = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Why do you want became a participant?')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dateOfBirth = forms.DateField(label='Date of birth', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2017)))
```